# How can I see the FPS in KSP?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

It's probably a very simple question, but I couldn't find the key to show the frame rate in KSP.

Comment: Don't think you can, at least not directly.  YouTube LPers see the frame rate in their recording software, if that's where the idea came from.

Comment: Well I see a lot of posts bragging/complaining about their FPS so I thought there is a way to see them easily.

Comment: That could be an external program, or it could just be people who know what low FPS looks like.

Answer (score 4):

#### New answer

Assuming you're playing KSP on Steam, you can now use [Steam's new FPS counter](http://kotaku.com/steams-new-fps-counter-makes-it-easier-to-obsess-over-f-1677380513). Thanks to Steam's cross-platform nature, this should allow you to see your FPS on Linux and OSX as well.

---

#### Old answer

You could always download the [trial version of FRAPS](http://www.fraps.com/download.php) to see your FPS.
The trial version only limits which features can be used, none of which are relevant to FPS monitoring.

If you happen to own a license for [AIDA64](http://www.aida64.com/) as well as any Logitech product with built-in LCD screen, such as the [G19](http://gaming.logitech.com/en-us/product/g19s-lcd-gaming-keyboard) or [G510 Keyboard](http://gaming.logitech.com/en-us/product/g510s-lcd-gaming-keyboard), or the [G13 Advanced Gameboard](http://gaming.logitech.com/en-us/product/g13-advanced-gameboard), then you can monitor your FPS through AIDA64's Logitech LCD app (needs to be configured and activated first).
However, the FPS monitoring features of that app require FRAPS to be installed, even if it's just the trial version.

FRAPS currently supports Windows XP, Vista, 7 and 8 and will work with DirectX or OpenGL applications.

Comment: You don't need to record any video or screenshots to get the FPS counter up anyway. I'd highly recommend FRAPS actually.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out. Sound like  it would help a lot, but this is half of the problem :) My slower computer runs Linux.

Comment: On Linux, use glc, VLC, or ffmpeg.  http://superuser.com/questions/280911/linux-equivalent-of-fraps